# OpenAPI.net - Duplicate components

Tags: c#, reference, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

Ḯ'm trying to merge several OpenAPI specs into a single OpenAPI document. However, some of the OpenAPI specs that im trying to merge, contains Components.Schemes with identical key names but different values/schemes. My initial solution was to check if a key already exists, and if it does, i simply change the key name to "KeyName2","KeyName3", and so on. This is the current code:

```
// Components --> Schemas
int iterator = 2
foreach (var schemas_ite in importedOpenApiDocument.Components.Schemas)
{
        if (document.Components.Schemas.ContainsKey(schemas_ite.Key))
        {
             string newSchemesString = schemas_ite.Key + iterator;
             document.Components.Schemas.Add(newSchemesString, schemas_ite.Value);
             iterator += 1
        }
        else
        {
             document.Components.Schemas.Add(schemas_ite.Key, schemas_ite.Value); 
        }
}
```

When im serializing the merged OpenAPI spec, the new keys exists as expected, but the values of the new keys are simply references to the previous identical key, even though the value/content of the scheme is different.

Output from the merged OpenAPI document is below:

```
components:
  schemas:
    ProblemDetails:
      type: object
      properties:
        title2:
    Subscription:
      type: string
    ProblemDetails2:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails'
    Subscription2:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Subscription'
```

As you can see, the ProblemDetails2 and Subscription2 is simply created with a ref to first schemes, even though the content is different. How do i fix this issue? I know there is function called SerializeAsV3WithoutReferences, but im not sure how to use it or what i should use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using .net, maybe you can try to add the following to your Startup.cs class

```
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(opt =>
{
   opt.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
});
```

or to your SwaggerConfig in the App_Start folder

```cs
GlobalConfiguration
    .Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.PrettyPrint();
        c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
    });
```